# pandas not matching initial index when I try to join/merge/loc

Tags: python, pandas

I've got 2 pd.series, one has datetimes and is short, the other has datetimes with matching values and is long.

I want to get a dataframe with indexes from the first series and corresponding values from the second series. Both have some duplicates. I can create a new object looping through the indexes, but there's got to be a better way? I tried join, merge and loc each time the resulting dataframe is longer than the first series of datetimes.

Comment: _I tried join, merge and loc each time the resulting dataframe is longer than the first series of datetimes._ Please provide a clear example of the input and expected output, as well as each of the methods you tried and their respective output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with merge() method:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

It would help a lot if you could provide a snippet of dataframes you are working on.